# Value is not getting set to IBOutlet NStextField

Tags: objective-c

I want to set the value of `NSTextField`.

//In .h Class//I have an

```
IBOutlet @property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *tId;
```

//In .m Class//

```
  @synthesize  tId;
```

In my XIB I have connected the `IBOulet` to the `FilesOwner`.

and in my .m class I am trying to set the value to the `NSTextField` in the method

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window

{enter code here

[tId setStringValue:@"1"];

return self;

}
```

But the value is not getting set.

Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Comment: You have a UITextField And you want to set Placeholder value for it..???

Comment: No it is an NSTextField and i want to set the value. Nothing like PlaceHolder.

Comment: @Namrata Witch type of value you want to set ????

Comment: Like Numbers...That is 1, 2, 3 like this

Comment: Oks you want to set Number on it

Comment: Yeah...But not sure why it is not getting set..!!!

Comment: Dont worry use my answer

Answer (score 1):

OKs Use this

```
      -(BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString*)partialString newEditingString:(NSString**)newString errorDescription:(NSString**)error
          {
            if([partialString length] == 0) {
            return YES;
          }

        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:partialString];

        if(!([scanner scanInt:0] && [scanner isAtEnd])) {
                 NSBeep();
                return NO;
              }

       return YES;
   }
```

And then set this formatter to your NSTextField:

```
       NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
      [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
      [textField setFormatter:formatter];
```

Comment: OnlyIntegerValueFormatter *formatter = [[OnlyIntegerValueFormatter alloc] init]; --  Is this line of code any refernce to the class?

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur help, but i have one more clarification in my init method code, i am using the [tId setStringValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tId.stringValue"]]. is the usage of the tid.StringValue is the same as the one that we use in XIB bindings for value? Or can it be anything, actually i am trying to read the data from user defaults.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: yeah..actually i am setting the value in another class and i am capturing in this field.

Comment: @Namratha Please Again clear your last question .... i cant understand about that what you set in xib

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood the question correctly. I'll address the problem "I try to set stringValue to NSTextField accessing it via IBOutlet, but value in text field doesn't change", not the problem "How to customize NSTextField, so it accepts only numeric values".

NSTextField value may not be set because

- method `initWithWindow:` isn't called
- IBOutlets aren't hooked up yet when you call `-[NSTextField setStringValue:]`.

Usually, IBOutlets are `nil` in initializers and are hooked up later. I'd move the line

```
[tId setStringValue:@"1"];
```

to method `- (void)awakeFromNib` and see if helps. According to docs

> When an object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet instance variables set.